# Formal Word/ Phrase for "major chunk of"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to write the following sentence:

The "major chunk of payments" under the conditional cash transfer scheme will be made when the child enters high school.

Since this is for an academic essay, I need to replace "major chunk of payments" with something more formal.

Some background: This scheme gives cash transfers at different stages of schooling,but the major payment is made on entering high school.

Comment: Major portion replaces replace major chunk.

Comment: How big is *a major chunk*? 10%? 90%?

Comment: @CanisLupus Approx 90%. Should I just write it in terms of percentage only?

Comment: That would be a very concise way to say it.

Comment: Concise works here:) It's an economics paper, so it won't look out of place. Thanks! But in general though, what could be a good substitute for this word in academic writing?

Comment: Significant portion

Answer (score 1):

> **Lion's share**
> /noun
>
> 1. the largest part or share, especially a disproportionate portion.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/lion%27s%20share)

Answer (score 1):

If it's more than 50%, you can simply refer to it as "the [***majority***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/majority)"...

> a number or percentage equaling more than half of a total
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/majority)*</sub>

To distinguish the amount of money paid from the number of payments made, you might want to call it the "payout" as opposed to the "payments":

> The majority of the payout is made when the child enters high school.